# Vue3 - pass multiple event listeners along with their handlers to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

in Vue3 I can do the following:

**Parent Component:**

```
<ChildComponent :props="{ id: 'the-id', class: 'the-class' }" />
```

**ChildComponent:**

```html
<template>
    <input v-bind="props" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        props: { type: Object }
    }
}
</script>
```

This will result in HTML like this:

```html
<input id="the-id" class="the-class" />
```

I'm still learning Vue and I was wondering if I could do the same thing with event listeners / handlers.

With reusable components I might need different event listeners / handlers, depending on where I use the component. In one form I might need only an `@input="..."` in the child component, in another form I might also need an `@blur="..."` or I might not need an event listener at all.

**Is it possible to do something similar to this?**

**ParentComponent:**

```
<ChildComponent :events="{ input: function() { alert('input!'); }, blur: function() { alert('blur!'); } } />
```

**ChildComponent:**

```html
<template>
    <input @events />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        props: { type: Object }
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you ;)

Comment: [passing functions as props](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/)

Answer (score 6):

You can also do something similar like you did with the props, by passing an object to `v-on`:

```
<input v-on="{ input: doThis, blur: doThat }"></button>
```

See here: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on

Answer (score 4):

The root element of a component [automatically inherits all non-prop attributes](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance) (including event listeners) applied to the component from the parent. So if `<input>` were really at the root in `ChildComponent`, you wouldn't need to declare anything, and you could simply apply attributes to `ChildComponent` as if it were the `input` itself:

```html
<ChildComponent id="the-id" class="the-class" @blur="onBlur" />
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-attribute-inheritance?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FParentComponent.vue)

However, this will break as soon as you add another element to `ChildComponent` because `<input>` would no longer be the root. It also would be a problem if you wanted to switch the root element (e.g., a `<label>` that wraps the `<input>`).

To [disable automatic attribute inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance), allowing control of where to apply the inherited attributes, set `inheritAttrs: false` in component options. (This doesn't need to be disabled when there are multiple root nodes, as it only applies for single-root components.) Then manually `v-bind` the [`$attrs` prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-properties.html#attrs) to any element within:

```html
<template>
  <label>My input: <input v-bind="$attrs"></label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-bind-inherited-attrs?file=src/components/ChildComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to define the different events though Vue's Custom Events; The custom events would allow the users of the component to choose which event to subscribe to and handle it accordingly.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html